# Can’t seem to avoid force unwrapping in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsdata, option-type, nsfilewrapper

**Update**: this is regarding a Mac app created with the Document-based Application template in Xcode, and I’m overriding

```
override func readFromFileWrapper(fileWrapper: NSFileWrapper, ofType typeName: String, error outError: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool
```

---

I’m trying to read in a file from an NSFileWrapper and it seems like I can't get away from having at least one `!` in there.

First, I tried

```
if let rtfData = files["textFile.rtf"]?.regularFileContents,
        newString = NSMutableAttributedString(data: rtfData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil) {
                text = newString
                return true
        }
```

So I get this error

> Value of optional type 'NSData?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

And I have to either cast `regularFileContents as NSData!` or I have to force unwrap it in the NSMutableAttributedString's initializer (`data: rtfData!`).

---

So then I tried

```
let rtfData = files["textFile.rtf"]?.regularFileContents

if (rtfData != nil) {
    if let newString = NSMutableAttributedString(data: rtfData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil) {
        text = newString
        return true
    }
}
```

Which results in

> Cannot find an initializer for type 'NSMutableAttributedString' that accepts an argument list of type '(data: NSData??, options: [String : String], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)'"

So I have to change the initializer to say `data: rtfData!!`, which I'm not even sure what that *means*.

Or, I can cast `regularFileContents as NSData?`, and then I can only use one `!` in the initializer.

**Update:** Here's another thing I’ve tried since posting. I figured the double `?` in `NSData??` could be due to me optionally unwrapping the NSFileWrapper `(files["textFile.rtf"]?`) so I tried this:

```
if let rtfWrapper = files["textFile.rtf"],
    rtfData = rtfWrapper.regularFileContents,
    newString = NSMutableAttributedString(data: rtfData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil) {
        text = newString
        return true
    }
```

The compiler **still** wants me to force unwrap NSData.

---

I am pretty thoroughly confused.

What is `NSData??`, why is it “doubly” optional, why is it the result of `.regularFileContents`, and how can I *safely*, without `!`-ing all the way, get the NSData and pass it to the NSMutableAttributedString’s intializer?

---

**Another update**

I figured maybe the `files` constant could be the source of another optional wrapping:

```
let files = fileWrapper.fileWrappers
```

But the compiler won't let me `if let` it. If I try, for example,

```
if let files = fileWrapper.fileWrappers {
    if let rtfFile = files["textFile.rtf"] {
        if let rtfData = rtfFile.regularFileContents {
            if let newString = NSMutableAttributedString(data: rtfData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil) {
                text = newString
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler gives this error:

> Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type

About `fileWrapper.fileWrappers`

The `fileWrapper` variable is a parameter of the method, which is

```
override func readFromFileWrapper(fileWrapper: NSFileWrapper, ofType typeName: String, error outError: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use optional binding for the file first, and then proceed from there:

```
if let file = files["textFile.rtf"],
    contents = file.regularFileContents,
    newString = NSMutableAttributedString(data: contents, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil) {
        text = newString
        return true
}
```

If you're using `fileWrappers` dictionary (a `[NSObject : AnyObject]`), you have to do some additional casting. This example is using a file I happen to have in that file wrapper, but hopefully it illustrates the idea:

```
var text: NSString!

func someMethod(fileWrapper: NSFileWrapper) {
    let files = fileWrapper.fileWrappers

    if let file = files["test.json"] as? NSFileWrapper,
        contents = file.regularFileContents,
        newString = NSString(data: contents, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)  {
            text = newString
            println(text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that, it didn't work either. In your snippet, the compiler would complain about `data: contents` and would only accept `data: contents!`

Comment: @kamera No, it wouldn't complain about `contents` being an optional, because it's not (we're doing optional binding here; this is why I broke it into two assignments, so each optional binding could take place in succession). I just tested it and it worked fine.

Comment: Could it be that my `files` constant is the issue? Where are you getting it in your snippet? Check out the update to my question.

Comment: Thanks. Is that iOS code? I wonder if my issue is specific to OS X.

Comment: Yes, but I updated my answer with more generic example and using `fileWrappers`. If nothing else, and additional issue is that `fileWrappers` is a `[NSObject : AnyObject]` dictionary so some additional casting is needed.

Comment: Yes!  `if let file = files["test.json"] as? NSFileWrapper` was the ticket. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your line:

```
files["textFile.rtf"]?.regularFileContents
```

Returns a doubly-wrapped optional. One for the dictionary look up, one for the `.regularFileContents`. When you did the `if let`, you unwrapped it once: that's why your error was:

```
// Value of optional type 'NSData?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

But then, on your second version, you just *check* if `rtfData` is nil - you don't unwrap it:

```
if (rtfData != nil)
```

Which gives you the doubly-wrapped optional.

The easiest way to get around it is to use `flatMap`:

```
if let rtfData = files["textFile.rtf"].flatMap({$0.regularFileContents}) {
    text = NSMutableAttributedString(data: rtfData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)
    return true
}
```

`flatMap` takes an optional, and unwraps it to put it into a function that *returns* an optional. If either the original optional, or the value returned from the function, evaluates to nil, the whole thing evaluates to nil. But the value it returns is only singly wrapped.

What `flatMap` is doing is basically:

```
if let lookup = files["textFile.rtf"] {
  if let rtfData = lookup.regularFileContents {
    let newString = NSMutableAttributedString(data: rtfData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil) 
    text = newString
    return true
  }
}
```

This code would work as well. Both methods safely unwrap `rtfData` twice.

Comment: Hmm. Stil getting **Value of optional type 'NSData?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?** at the `data: rtfData` part of the initializer

Comment: Changed it - the newString shouldn't have been inside the if let statement.

Comment: Same thing; still getting the same compiler error. Could it be the `files` constant itself? Check out the latest update to my question

Comment: Thanks. I marked Rob's answer as the correct answer as it resolved my particular issue but I appreciate your insight regarding `flatMap`.

Comment: Yeah, I completely missed the problem with the casting. @Rob 's answer is on the money.